# Flow of charges from lower to higher concentration, concentration gradient in intrinsic semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In (electronic circuits) by  Neamen,it is mentioned that some charges flow lower concentration to higher concentration..Why does this happen?Also,does concentration gradient exist in an intrinsic semiconductor?If yes,then why?

Answer (score 1):

Charge will flow against the gradient of concentration if there is an electric field present.  Note also that even without a field present charges flow *both ways*.  The net current, however, is zero.

An intrinsic semiconductor *can* have a concentration gradient if it is not homogeneous.  A single crystal is  homogeneous except for a small region at its surfaces.  Concentration gradients can appear near the surface, but not in the bulk.

Comment: Without applying an electric field why do charges flow both the ways?I have heard since school days that flow is always from higher concentration to lower concentration so that it evens out..I don't see any reason for flow from lower to higher concentration

Comment: The carriers are *diffusing*.   They move in all directions regardless of their charge.  If there is a concentration gradient, more will move toward lower concentration than toward higher concentration.  That's because there are more carriers available in the high-concentration regions in the first place to move.